# Reading files in android outside of onCreate()

Tags: android

I am wondering does reading files in android only works under onCreate() of an activity?
I having this question because my reading process works when the reading process is in side of onCreate() or in side a method that is called under onCreate.

Following is what I am using for reading a file

```
try {
            file="";
            InputStream ish =     this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.regular_hero_deck);
            BufferedReader brh = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(ish));
            if(ish!=null){
                while ((data = brh.readLine()) != null)   {
                    file+=data;
                }
            }
            ish.close();
            regularDeckHero =new Deck<Hero>("heroDeck",file);
        }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error : reading hero deck");}
```

Solution: it is the problem with

```
InputStream ish =     this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.regular_hero_deck);
```

this.getResources() is doesn't give what I wanted, the resources you need is the one from your MainActivty pass this resources to this should work.

Comment: plz accept any answer if that solved your problem...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works every where, even outside an Activity..

may be the below line

```
InputStream ish =     this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.regular_hero_deck);
```

causes the problem.. because you use this (current instance which is an Activity)..

instead  by getting application context refrence you can still say

```
InputStream ish =     context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.regular_hero_deck);
```

Comment: how should I create context for getResources()?

Comment: what I did is passing the resources from my main activity all the way to the class which I need it. It doesn't give me error now.

Comment: @user1727416.. good to know.. a better way would be passing the context and getting resources.. you can do that like this, **yourActivity.this.getApplicationContext()**. and pass this to the other class and get resources..

Answer (score 0):

change this line..

```
InputStream ish =     this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.regular_hero_deck);
```

to

```
InputStream ish =     YourActivityname.this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.regular_hero_deck);
```

e.g. YourActivityname is like mainActivity

Comment: If I do that I get an error saying                                   "No enclosing instance of the type KSScreen is accessible in scope" KKScreen is my main activity  I noticed that YourActivityname.this.somemethod is allowed only when you are using the method inside of YourActivityname.